# access to state from another module

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I need to access to state form another module for make a mutation.

module a has a state A .
module b has a state B .

I want make a mutation in module b but I also need the A state to complete this.

Maybe it's possible to make a global state and access from all modules ?

Comment: You likely can do this with `rootState` instead of `state`. Is this what you asked about?

Comment: I thinks this is it , but I don't know how and where implement it

Comment: Depends on where you intend to access it. Please, provide your actual code so improvements could be suggested.

Comment: It's hard to say exactly what's going wrong, but take a look here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#module-local-state

Comment: just save data on vuex store in the first place and do not use local state.